# How to add dynamically custom attributes to quote and order in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quote, custom-attributes

I'm developing an extension which requires adding fields to quote (and later to order as well) dynamically. Should I make two extra tables in the database, one for quote and second one for order, or is there a better way to store the new data? My extra fields have identifiers created by shop admin so I cannot hardcode thir names into xml or somewhere like that. I've been seeking some solutions for quite a time but can't find anything interesting on this topic.